# What features are limited in the demo?

Tags: disgaea-5-demo, disgaea-5

I am trying to level up my mages fire magic, and it is at least level 20 by now, but still only has the single square targeting. In previous games, I would have at least 2 square by now. It is possible the additional targets do not appear the demo.

I know that several shops, as well as the Item World, are closed off in the demo. Are there any game play features, such as growth or items that do not require shops, that just will not appear until the full game?

Comment: This might be difficult to answer, at present. What your asking requires a comparison with the complete title to confirm correctness, and the game is only presently available in Japan.

Comment: This question can probably wait for an answer for the full game to be released. But I did ask elsewhere and I was mistaken anyway. My main evidence of actual limitations was the target zone. But it was changed to needing a skill shop in D4, so it isn't actually being limited. So I imagine I will find out the answer is "Nothing. Only certain shops are unavailable and any features that go with them."